# Comma before "and" in "alleging harassment, and retaliation, which has now been..."

Tags: punctuation, commas, conjunctions

> Please be advised that the clerks Intake Specialist Unit  is in receipt of the complaint you filed against Maple Lee alleging harassment, and retaliation, which has now been assigned Intake #123425.

My question is, should there be a comma before *and* in "alleging harassment, and retaliation"?

Comment: In ordinary written English, the comma is unnecessary and even out of place there; however, this appears to be legal writing, for which it may carry some special significance.

Answer (score 1):

No. It adds nothing. No punctuation should be used unless it serves a purpose.

Answer (score -1):

No, not in this case.  The common is only needed before "and" if the list is three or more items.